# How can I create multiple tkinter widgets with different names in a loop?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I should be able to use a loop to do the below instead of writing out more widgets than I'll ever need and shorten my code.This is the way I'm doing it now:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/database')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Drug FROM database where current >= 1")
allrec = cursor.fetchall()
numrec = len(allrec)
cursor.execute("SELECT Drug FROM database where current >= 1")
results = cursor.fetchone()
if numrec == 0:
    exit
else:
    c1=Checkbutton(frame1,variable=var1)
    c1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nw')
    c1.config(bg='black')
    e1=Entry(frame1, bg="black", fg="white")
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW)
    e1.delete(0, END)
    for row in results:
        e1.insert(END, *results)
results = cursor.fetchone()
if numrec <= 1:
    quit
else:
    c2=Checkbutton(frame1,variable=var2)
    c2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='nw')
    c2.config(bg='black')
    e2=Entry(frame1, bg="black", fg="white")
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NW)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    for row in results:
        e2.insert(END, *results)

    record 3 ........
    record 4 ........
    .......
    .......
    record 15 .......
```

This creates 15 check boxes and entry boxes with different names so I can insert records from my database.

Comment: Use a list, then access with `record[0]` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having fifteen variables named `c1`, `c2`... `c15`, create a single list which will hold all of your checkbuttons. Do the same for your entries and vars.

```
checkbuttons = []
entries = []
vars = []
for i in range(numrec):
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    var = IntVar()
    check_button=Checkbutton(frame1,variable=var)
    check_button.grid(row=i,column=0,sticky='nw')
    check_button.config(bg='black')
    entry=Entry(frame1, bg="black", fg="white")
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky=NW)
    entry.delete(0, END)
    for row in results:
        entry.insert(END, *results)
    checkbuttons.append(check_button)
    entries.append(entry)
    vars.append(var)
```

Now instead of getting e.g. the sixth entry with `e6`, you get it with `entries[5]`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get from a list. All I'm getting is a long decimal number

Comment: To get what from a list?

Comment: In the above example how do I get the text in the entry box?

Comment: `entries[whatever].get()`